# Change Rails 4 production.rb constants based on request.url

Tags: ruby, actionmailer, production-environment, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Please can someone point me in the right direction for what I'm sure is a simple problem, but is causing me to go round in circles.I have three domains

1. .com
2. .com.au
3. .co.nz

   I'm trying to keep a single code base for maintenance.

I've done some manual localisation work **to change titles, contact details etc based on the url**, using `request.original_url and stripping out the relevant parts and setting some constants in the application controller (SITE, EMAIL, TELEPHONE etc).`

It all works fine, except for my `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings in the production.rb.`

These obviously should change so the **localised email account** is used **(info@...com or .com.au etc)** but

I can't get the constants to be initialised before the environment is loaded. It makes perfect sense why it's not working, but I have no idea how to fix it.

I've tried putting it in **initializers**, the **application.rb** and setting it in the **production.rb** itself. If I move the code anywhere out of the application controller I get a no method error on **request.original_url**.

Is there a way of pulling out `mailer settings` so they can be exposed to variables? Or is the `production.rb` loaded at app start up and after that is unaffected by the end user.

Also, even though the language is remaining the same should I look at i18n for manipulating the site for these features? or is it not worth the effort for the few variables I want to change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know that constants in Ruby are mutable? Meaning you can change any constant that is already defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change settings in runtime:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings[:host] = 'yourhostfromrequest'
```

Comment: ok so I can shift the mailer config to each of the mailer.rb files, do you know how I can set this during runtime?
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = SITE

The SITE variable isn't defined until I can pull the url request

Comment: This is practically the same as my answer.

Comment: You can for example use define multiple constants for your sites. Or even Site model with all SITE, EMAIL, TELEPHONE configuration in it. And you can set site_id after request in user model, and get all needed data in mailer using site_id. There is not big chance that user will be accessing two sites at the same time as it seems. And also it'll help you with any future interactions with users, because you will already know what site he used for registation.

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the constants in your mailers, since constants in Ruby are *mutable*.

Comment: Hi - Yes I knew they can be changed, but they were showing as undefined on push to production.